# Почему нет знака за метку, хотя условия выполнены?

Tags: поддержка, знаки

Обратил внимание, что у меня выполнены условия для получения серебряного знака за метку [поддержка](/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%ba%d0%b0), но знак не был присвоен:

1. Есть [80 авторских ответов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a181472%20%5b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%ba%d0%b0%5d%20wiki%3ano%20is%3aa) и 419 рейтинга за них (судя по [вкладке про метки](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/181472/nick-volynkin?tab=tags))
2. В целом по метке задано более 100 вопросов (это условие для того, чтобы знак вообще хоть кому-то присваивался)
3. Все знаки на метке на сайте [присваиваются 4:00 до 4:02 по моему местному времени](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/108/c), соответствующее универсальное глобальное время - 22:00. В последний раз это было 4 часа назад и в это время условия уже выполнялись.

Однако, знака нет. Что не так?

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Многие знаки присваиваются раз в сутки, в 4:00 UTC.

Если знака нет, нужно подождать хотя бы до 4:05.

Посмотреть время можно в меню с достижениями:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: сам спросил - сам ответил :-D

Comment: @Grundy ирония в том, что вопрос мой тоже с меткой [meta-tag:поддержка]. Спасение утопающих... :)

Comment: Безотходное производство :-)